# Not able to use collation in mongoTemplate springboot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Below is my Queries:-
   I am not able to add collation in my queries to get the data in case insensitive sorted way.

```
  public Page<BaseProfileEntity> searchCustomProfil(String searchType){
     Query query = new Query().with(pageable);
     Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
     criteria.orOperator(Criteria.where("companyCode").regex(searchType, i),
                        Criteria.where("companyName").regex(searchType, i));

                        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(searchModel.getDirection())) {

            if (searchModel.getDirection().equalsIgnoreCase("asc")) {
                query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "companyName"));
            } else {
                query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "companyName"));
            }

        }entities =  (List<BaseProfileEntity>) ((List<?>) (mongoTemplate.find(query.addCriteria(criteria), Profile2Entity.class)));
        respEntities =  PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(entities, pageable,() -> mongoTemplate.count(query, Profile2Entity.class));return respEntities;}
```

Comment: During to my tryings - it looks like regex can't be used together with collation.

Answer (score 1):

query.collation(...)
caseFirst:off is default value, so you don't need do anything